# Darle un valor numerico a cadena de caracteres en php

Tags: php

suponiendo que las letras estan agrupadas y tienen valores numericos, por ejemplo:

Q,A,Z=1

W,S,X=2

E,D,C=3

R,F,V=4

T,G,B=5

Y,H,N=6

U,J,M=7

I,K=8

O,L=9

P,Ñ=0

como sumo los valores de alguna palabra, por ejemplo: HOLA

H=6 + O=9 + L=9 + A=1 == 25

USANDO ARREGLOS Y LA FUNCION FOR

se debe ver de la siguiente manera

[image: Imagen de muestra de la vista]

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title>Informacion de Cadenas</title> 
</head>

<?php
$arraycad = array(
    1=>"q","a","z",
    2=>"w","s","x",
    3=>"e","d","c",
    4=>"r","f","v",
    5=>"t","g","b",
    6=>"y","h","n",
    7=>"u","j","m", 
    8=>"i","k",
    9=>"o","l",
    0=>"p","ñ");
?>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" name="formulario">
    <br>Cadena: <input type="text" id="cadena" name="cadena"><br>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Buscar valor" id="buscar" name="buscar"><br>
    <br>Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor">
</form>

    <?php $cadena = ['cadena'] ?>

        <br>Valor de cadena:<div id="valcad" name="valcad">
        <?php for($i=0;$i< count($cadena);$i++):?>
                <?php echo $cadena[$i];?><br>
                    <?php endfor?><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @Jakala ya lo comente

Answer (score 0):

El uso de PHP complicaría un poco la solución, por lo que si el programa solo hará esta tarea lo mejor sería usar JavaScript y con esto evitar el uso de ajax.

```js
const numeros = [
  ["p","ñ"],
  ["q","a","z"],
  ["w","s","x"],
  ["e","d","c"],
  ["r","f","v"],
  ["t","g","b"],
  ["y","h","n"],
  ["u","j","m"],
  ["i","k"],
  ["o","l"]
];

document.getElementById('buscar').onclick = buscarValor;

function buscar(letra) {
  return numeros.findIndex(t => { return t.find(i => i === letra.toLowerCase())});
}

function buscarValor() {
  const input = document.getElementById('cadena').value;
  let total = 0;
  
  if (input) {
    total = [...input].reduce((acumulado, letra) => {
      return acumulado += buscar(letra);
    }, 0);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('valor').value = total;
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <br>Cadena: <input type="text" id="cadena" name="cadena"><br>
    <br><button value="" id="buscar" name="buscar">Buscar valor</button><br>
    <br>Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor">
</form>
```

**Edit:** Bueno, me acabo de dar cuenta de que uno de los requerimientos es que sea con un ciclo `for` por lo que te adjunto el código escrito ya en PHP. Solo es la lógica principal, por lo que tú te encargarías de implementar la parte de recepción y envío de datos al cliente a través de peticiones HTTP.

```
function buscar($letra) {
    $letra = strtolower($letra);
    $arraycad = array(
        array("p","ñ"),
        array("q","a","z"),
        array("w","s","x"),
        array("e","d","c"),
        array("r","f","v"),
        array("t","g","b"),
        array("y","h","n"),
        array("u","j","m"),
        array("i","k"),
        array("o","l")
    );
    
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arraycad); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($arraycad[$i]); $j++) {
            if ($arraycad[$i][$j] === $letra) return $i;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

$palabra = str_split("hola");

$total = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($palabra); $i++) {
    $total += buscar($palabra[$i]);
}

echo $total;
# 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Este problema sería fácil de resolver si no fuese porque podría tener [cadenas de caracteres multibyte](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.mbstring.php) con encoding diferente (ñ, á, é...). Afortunadamente PHP tiene [funciones mb_](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.mbstring.php) para facilitarle un poco la vida al desarrollador en estos casos, sin embargo requieren algo de ajuste en la implementación.

Creo que es más eficiente, para escribir el código y mantenerlo, crear un array asociativo para cada letra y asignarle el valor respectivo.

En este caso se usa un `for` de `$i=0` hasta el final `mb_strlen($palabra)` para recorrer cada letra de la cadena. 
En circunstancias "normales" serviría usar [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para comprobar si `$letra` está en `$arraycad`. Pero estamos usando multibyte, entonces hay que comprobarlo por nosotros mismos manualmente, por eso la línea `foreach($arraycad as $key=>$value)`. Si el valor `$key == $letra`, entonces se acumula en `$total` su valor, `$value`. Finalmente se retorna `$total`.

```
<?php

function pvalor($palabra) {
    $arraycad = array(
        'a'=>1, 'b'=>5, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>3, 'e'=>3, 'f'=>4, 'g'=>5,
        'h'=>6, 'i'=>8, 'j'=>7, 'k'=>8, 'l'=>9, 'm'=>7, 'n'=>6,
        'o'=>9, 'p'=>0, 'q'=>1, 'r'=>4, 's'=>2, 't'=>5, 'u'=>7,
        'v'=>4, 'w'=>2, 'x'=>2, 'y'=>6, 'z'=>1, 
        'ñ'=>0, 'á'=>1, 'é'=>3, 'í'=>8, 'ó'=>9, 'ú'=>7
    );
    $total = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($palabra); $i++) {
        $letra = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($palabra, $i, 1));
        foreach($arraycad as $key=>$value) {
            if($key == $letra) {
                $total += $value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Pruebas:

```
echo pvalor("hola"); // 25
echo pvalor("año37"); // 10
echo pvalor("El País"); // 23
```

Ahora es solo cuestión que adaptes eso a tu página web. Recuerda usar los charsets y encabezados correctos si te da problemas de visualización en el HTML.